# Java Scanner.readLine consumes new line character, but when using println doesn't consume new line character

Tags: java

## Code

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str="";
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i= 0; i<3;i++) {
            str = scanner.nextLine();
            strs.add(str);
        }
        System.out.println(strs);
    }
}
```

## Console

```
1        // input
2        // input
[1, , 2]
```

I want to input three times. But only two time works. I thought scanner.nextLine consume new line character. But when i use `System.out.println`, it works three time.

## Code

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str="";
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i= 0; i<3;i++) {
            str = scanner.nextLine();
            strs.add(str);
            System.out.println("String: " + str);
        }
        System.out.println(strs);
    }
}
```

## Console

```
1         // input
String: 1         
2         // input
String: 2         
3         // input
String: 3         
[1, 2, 3]
```

My environment is mac monterey 12.3.1 intel chip. I use adoptium temurin java 11. Why it works diffrent via using println?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of the `nextLine()` method states

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. **This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end**. [...]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Pressing the enter key corresponds to inputting two characters: a new line (\n) and a carriage return (\r). Both of these are line separators. When you type your first input and then press enter, the `Scanner` returns the first line, stops and then awaits for the second input (your second `nextLine()` invocation). However, since there is already a line terminator (the second line terminator left from the previous read), once you enter your second input, your scanner immediately halts at the beginning and returns an empty `String`. After that, the same thing keeps happening where only one read out of two seems to be taken.

What you need to do is to place an extra `nextLine()` **between every read (not after every read)** to get rid of that "extra" line terminator character.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = "";
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Enter three numbers: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    str = scanner.nextLine();
    // The last iteration does not need to get rid of that "extra" line terminator
    // because there is no following read; 
    // otherwise you would be forced to input an extra number
    if (i < 2) {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    strs.add(str);
}
System.out.println(strs);
```

Alternatively, you can ask for the input with a print message before every read. In this way, the `Scanner`'s internal cursor will be moved forward the "extra" line separator due to the text written on screen and allowing you to retrieve the correct input with a single `nextLine()`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = "";
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    str = scanner.nextLine();
    strs.add(str);
}
System.out.println(strs);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks. Are you saying that when I print message, the scanner's cursor is moved?

Comment: @seokh1213 exactly. The console is the same resource where the system.out prints to and the system.in reads from. So if you print something between a read and another the scanner's internal cursor must be moved to start reading from where the input happens.

Comment: Thinking about it, that's correct. Thanks for the quick reply. Have a nice day.